# Processing a SOAP web service response in php

Tags: php, web-services, soap-client

I have .Net web service that has been running for years and would like to now be able to call and retrieve content using php. The service correctly returns a response:

```
 <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
      <Lang_Country_Region>Chinese - China</Lang_Country_Region>
      <twoLetter>zh-CN</twoLetter>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
      <Lang_Country_Region>Dutch - The Netherlands</Lang_Country_Region>
      <twoLetter>nl-NL</twoLetter>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
  <Lang_Country_Region>English - United States</Lang_Country_Region>
  <twoLetter>en-US</twoLetter>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
  <Lang_Country_Region>French - France</Lang_Country_Region>
  <twoLetter>fr-FR</twoLetter>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table5" msdata:rowOrder="4">
  <Lang_Country_Region>German - Germany</Lang_Country_Region>
  <twoLetter>de-DE</twoLetter>
</Table>
```

I get this result with this php code:

```
$result = $client->lstSupLang($params)->lstSupLangResult;
```

I am stuck here, I am using the SoapClient to make these calls.

How do I read the Soap body/elements in the response?

**UPDATE:** So now I have retrieved the data in the following manner:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result->any);
```

I am just not sure how to parse out the content that exists in $xml:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [NewDataSet] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
[Table] => Array ( 
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Lang_Country_Region] => Chinese - China [twoLetter] => zh-CN ) 
[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Lang_Country_Region] => Dutch - The Netherlands [twoLetter] => nl-NL ) 
[2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Lang_Country_Region] => English - United States [twoLetter] => en-US ) 
[3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Lang_Country_Region] => French - France [twoLetter] => fr-FR ) 
[4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Lang_Country_Region] => German - Germany [twoLetter] => de-DE ))))
```

How can I read through this using php?

Comment: Hi! I changed your tags ; the fact that the webservice is written is .Net has nothing to do with your problem. I have worked with SOAP webservices written in PHP before.

Comment: Ok, and I realize that, I am new to php, long time VB, C# coder. Trying get php to retrieve the same content.

Comment: Sure! but you'll get more help with the proper tags ;) I don't know php though, so I can't help you much. Have you looked at existing libraries to parse SOAP responses ?

Comment: Oh yea, I am moving through it, just having some issues here. Need a little bump to figure out how to break this result up. The rest of the php I think I can handle.

Comment: have you tried simply iterating on `foreach ($country as $xml)` and using `$country->Lang_CountryRegion` ?

Comment: foreach expects an array, the $xml is a simpleXmlObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

```
$count= 0;

foreach ($xml->children() as $values) {
    while($row = $values[$count]) {
        echo $row->Table[$count]->Lang_Country_Region . "<br>";
        echo $row->Table[$count]->twoLetter . "<br>";
        $count = $count + 1;
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is the right way, would like to see alternatives. But it does output the result without all of the SOAP.